# MongoDB switch key-value pairs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Is there an aggregation-query to convert the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "aaa",
      "values": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
      "key": "bbb",
      "values": [4,5,6]
    }
  ]
}
```

To this structure?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "aaa": "1,2,3"
    },
    {
      "bb": "4,5,6"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some hints or keywords for which aggregation command I could search next, are also helpful ...

**UPDATE:**
I am using MongoDB 3.4.3, so unfortunately `$arrayToObject` will not work. So I guess, the question is way more fundamental:

Is there any way to set field names generic (according to some other value) for MongoDB 3.4.3 or lower?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

To switch keys and values into an actual JSON key/value pair you could utilise [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).
Although first you would have to change the field name `key` and `value` into just `k` and `v` as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "k": "aaa",
      "v": [1,2,3]
    },
    {
      "k": "bbb",
      "v": [4,5,6]
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you've modified the document fields, you use operator `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
              { $project : { data : { $arrayToObject : "$data" }}}
]);
```

Which will output as below:

```
{
  "data": {
    "aaa": [1, 2, 3],
    "bbb": [4, 5, 6]
  }
}
```

Note that `$arrayToObject` array aggregation operator is available in MongoDB v3.4.4+

See also [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) for the reverse aggregation operator.

If you're also wanting to convert the value of array `[1, 2, 3]` into a single string of `"1,2,3"` you may be able to utilise [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) string operators.

See also more aggregation [Array Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-array/) and [String Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-string/) on the manual.

Comment: Unfortunately we are running on 3.4.3 ... Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I would suggest to do revision upgrade from 3.4.3 to the latest 3.4.x if it's possible. See [upgrade MongoDB revision](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-revision/)